# Random text and counter for pairs of letters

Tags: python

I am using this which is successful in creating a counter for letters relative to the previous pair.

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    last = next(it) + next(it)
    for curr in it:
        yield last, curr
        last = last[1]+curr


valid = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ')

def valid_pair((last, curr)):
    return last[0] in valid and last[1] in valid and curr in valid


def make_markov(text):
    markov = defaultdict(Counter)
    lowercased = (c.lower() for c in text)
    for p, q in ifilter(valid_pair, pairwise(lowercased)):
        markov[p][q] += 1
    return markov
```

But i would now like to generate random text with each letter depending on the counter for the previous pair. Here is the code used when a letter only depends on the previous letter.

```
def genrandom(model, n):
    curr = choice(list(model)) 
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield curr
        if curr not in model:   
            curr = choice(list(model))
        d = model[curr]   
        target = randrange(sum(d.values()))
        cumulative = 0
        for curr, cnt in d.items():
            cumulative += cnt
            if cumulative > target:
                break
```

I am having trouble adapting it to this second configuration, the output isn't consistent with what i would expect. Thanks!

Comment: The first group of functions do not work. You are using Counter (collections?) that was new in py3k together with ifilter (itertools ?) that disappeared in py3k. Is that correct ?

Comment: Of course it works in python 2.7 with addition of: from collections import Counter, defaultdict;
from itertools import ifilter;
from random import choice, randrange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you forgot that curr is twoletter combination. The last loop should be changed and curr constructed after it:

```
    for newcurr, cnt in d.items():
        cumulative += cnt
        if cumulative > target:
            break

    curr = curr[1] + newcurr
```

Also yield should be changed to produce just one character at a time